# GitLab CI_JOB_TOKEN does not authenticate with private python repository

Tags: python, authentication, gitlab, gitlab-ci, token

I tried to use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` in a GitLab CI pipeline to install a Python Package from a different project's package registry.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) i should just have to add my project to the allowlist of the corresponding project and run the pipeline.

However i always get the following 401 error when running this command

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://__token__:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projId>/packages/pypi/simple <package>
```

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://__token__:****@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projId>/packages/pypi/simple
WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projId>/packages/pypi/simple/<package>/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package> (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <package>
WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projId>/packages/pypi/simple/pip/
```

I tried to remove the allow list protections completely and it still did not work.

As a workaround i just added a secret variable in form of an Access Token to the pipelines in the GUI and with that it works, but this seems rather hacky since i need to update the token every few weeks.

Did i miss anything in the documentation and the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` does not have access to these registries ?

Comment: Are you a member of the other project that contains the package? Maybe also try using the username `gitlab-ci-token` instead of `__token__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GitLab PyPI registry authentication documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/index.html#authenticate-with-a-ci-job-token), you should use the username `gitlab-ci-token` when authenticating with a job token.

This might be confusing because some [other examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/index.html#using-requirementstxt) use `__token__` even though GitLab does not accept this username unless you are using an access token literally named `__token__`. `__token__` is normally used for tokens on PyPI.org, however.

Answer (score 0):

[sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech) provided the answer in the comments.

Use the username `gitlab-ci-token` instead of `__token__`.